# Element selection using xPath

Tags: xpath, selenium, traversal

I am trying to write a test automation code and having a hard time finding an element using Xpath in the below structure.

```
<div id="270590-bar" class="chart-row clearfix" style="display: block;">
    <div class="bar-col float">
        <div class="bar-wrapper">
           <div class="topic-name-wrapper" style="background-color: transparent;">Business</div>
           <div class="bar" style="width:170px"></div>
        </div>
    <div style="float:left;position:relative; ">
        <div class="level-dd-fake">Intermediate</div>
        <select id="270590-level" class="level-dropdown level-select">
    </div>
    <div id="270590-un" class="topic unsubscribe" style="float:left; margin: 0px 0px 0px 1px !important;"></div>
</div>
```

There are several data rows which will use the same set of lines as above for each row.
When I give the value inside `class="topic-name-wrapper"` eg:- Business

I want to select the `DropDown` element at `class="level-dropdown level-select"`

Hope the question is clear and any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: To select the `select` with that class you can use `//select[@class='level-dropdown level-select']` - but I don't understand what you mean with 'When I give the values inside ...' - that I suppose is an additional condition

Comment: Actually the interface looks like this.http://www.freeimagehosting.net/n55xi    I want to get the select element next to "Business"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you need something like that:

```
//div[*[.='Business']]/following-sibling::div/select
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. can you explain a little bit about this part of the Xpath?  `//div[*[.='Business']]`

Comment: @ras, `//div[*[.='Business']]` will find `div` with any child node (`*`) that have text 'Business'. Dot is the same as `text()='Business'`. Good reading on xpath can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx

Comment: `//div[*[.='Business']]/following-sibling::div/select` literally means "the SELECT contained within the DIV that is a following sibling-node of the DIV that contains a node whose text value is 'Business'".

Comment: FYI, `.='Business'` is not the same as `text()='Business'`.  `text()` matches a **single text node**, whereas `.` matches **the text value of the node**.  It's a subtle difference.  In `<div id='x'>A <span>B</span> C</div>`, `//x/.` is "A B C", whereas `//x/text()` is the set of nodes "A" and "C".